# Sum multiprocessing worker output arrays rather than returning the whole list of results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I understand how to use Python's `multiprocessing` module for parallel processing by splitting a job into chunks, passing it to a pool of workers, then compiling a list of results. How do I process the outputs from a pool of workers on-the-fly, rather than first getting the entire list of results and then processing it altogether?

This is important when the output of interest is the sum (or similar aggregation function) of a large number of results. Storing all results in memory is slow and unnecessary, and may not even be possible if the system memory is insufficient to store all the results.

I understand how to do this with, e.g. [an incrementing counter](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing). But in my case, the outputs are arrays and I have no idea how best to sum them on-the-fly.

**The minimal working example**

The real-life use case is in kernel density estimation, but I have distilled it down to this example. I have a class with a method that takes an array as input and returns an array of the same size.  I've been using numpy for obvious reasons.

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def generate_array(self, input_arr):
        return np.exp(-(input_arr - self.val) ** 2)
```

I create a large list of objects from this class and then pass the *same* input array to the `generate_array` method of each in turn. I ultimately want the sum of these arrays.

Here are three straightforward approaches to computing this using the standard serial loop approach, `map` and `imap` with different chunk sizes.

```
import numpy as np
import operator
from functools import partial
from time import time
import multiprocessing as mp   

def serial_evaluation(obj_arr, input_arr):
    return reduce(operator.add, (t.generate_array(input_arr) for t in obj_arr))


def parallel_func(obj, input_arr=None):
    return obj.generate_array(input_arr)


def parallel_evaluation(obj_arr, input_arr):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    the_func = partial(parallel_func, input_arr=input_arr)
    z = pool.map(the_func, obj_arr)
    return np.array(z).sum(axis=0)


def parallel_evaluation_imap(obj_arr, input_arr, chunksize=1):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    z = np.zeros_like(input_arr)
    the_func = partial(parallel_func, input_arr=input_arr)
    jobs = pool.imap(the_func, obj_arr, chunksize=chunksize)
    for x in jobs:
        z += x
    return z

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 20000

    # create array of objects of type MyClass
    obj_arr = [MyClass(t) for t in np.random.rand(n)]
    # define input array
    input_arr = np.linspace(-2, 3, n)

    tic = time()
    res_serial = serial_evaluation(obj_arr, input_arr)
    print "Serial evaluation in %f s" % (time()- tic)

    tic = time()
    res_parallel = parallel_evaluation(obj_arr, input_arr)
    print "Parallel evaluation in %f s" % (time()- tic)

    # different imap chunksizes
    chunksizes = [1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 2048, 8192]
    res_parallel_imap = {}
    for c in chunksizes:
        tic = time()
        res_parallel_imap[c] = parallel_evaluation_imap(obj_arr, input_arr, chunksize=c)
        print "Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize %d) in %f s" % (c, time()- tic)
```

Which, on my 8 core machine, outputs

```
Serial evaluation in 7.657961 s
Parallel evaluation in 4.888544 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 1) in 11.662317 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 4) in 5.779365 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 16) in 5.929825 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 64) in 4.487672 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 256) in 4.114722 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 1024) in 4.600147 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 2048) in 5.048849 s
Parallel imap evaluation (chunksize 8192) in 7.285429 s
```

I'm not expecting an 8-fold speed improvement, but less than 2 suggests significant multiprocessing overhead to me. The `map` version also chews through my system RAM, because it has to generate the 20000 x 20000 array before aggregating. This won't scale to meet my real use case requirements. The `imap` version doesn't have the same RAM issue (except at the highest chunk size), and is the current frontrunner.

How else might I approach this problem?  Ideas I have considered:

- Aggregate results returned by workers on the fly in a different way? I feel like [this article on PyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html) might be adapted, but I'm not sure how.
- Use a shared and writeable array with a global lock, along the lines of [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing). I didn't manage to implement that properly (example code greatly welcome here).

Comment: I can see that you did'nt try `imap_unordered`. As you only sum return values, you are not concerned by the order. I think it would be my first choice.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. As a quick sanity check: do you think my approach is generally OK? I haven't missed anything major?

Comment: I can see no evident error: you have a cpu-bound problem so you use multiprocessing, `imap` or `imap_unordered` give a generator, so you do not need to build everything in memory, the main program that consumes the queue only does an addition, when producers  call `exp` so the queue should not become too big. This last point is IMHO the only point to control here.